# Orchestration Design to pass a scenario

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk-deployment, biztalk-orchestrations

I have to develop an orchestration which uses a start orchestration shape followed by send port.

[image]

**Scenario:** If a "Sendport4" failed to send the message, I don't have to execute "Starting Orchestration Shape".

But in my case, when "sendport4" is getting failed, It is calling "Start Orchestraton Shape".

To handle this schenario, I tried to put the exception handling, But didn't worked.

Can any one please help, what can do handle this?

Comment: Is the Delivery Notification on the port connected to Send_4 enabled?

Comment: I think your asking about the option, which is under "Transaport Advanced Option" --> Order Delivery Checked or not, Correct? I tried that too, Still, I'm calling "Start Orchestration Shape" after "Sendport4". Please let me know.

Comment: No, it is not Ordered Delivery, that is on the Receive Port, you want the send port. Click on the Send Port Shape in the Orchestration and look for Delivery Notification.  By default it is set to None, you want to change it to Transmitted.

Comment: I've seen that option on Sendport, Is send port need to be Two-Way tranmission? FYI, I'm using one-way send port and I'm dealing with File Type transmission.

Comment: No it doesn't need to be a two-way to enable that.  By enabling Delivery Notification you tell it to send a ACK or NACK message back.  If it fails the NACK will cause the Orchestration to throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Delivery Notification to Transmitted on the Send Port shape in the Orchestration.

Comment: This. Also, use exception handling to handle the DeliveryNotificationException that will be thrown by the runtime after you set DeliveryNotification option to Transmitted.

Comment: I found DeliverFailureException. but didn't found "DeliveryNotificationException", Could you please tell me, what is the fully qualified name for "DeliveryNotificationException",

Comment: Here I'm dealing with Sendport File Adapter, does all the above setting works for this kind of transmission? Please let me know if there any other settings need to done.

Comment: This setting works to the point that point of the BizTalk adapter having transmitted the message.  With file, yes this will mean that it has arrived in that folder.  With some other protocols it doesn't necessarily mean that it has arrived at the target system, for example with SMTP it just means that BizTalk has delivered it to the mail server, not that the intended recipient has receive the e-mail.